# Unique attribute only when not null

Tags: sql, null, unique, sql-server-2014

I want to define an unique column, but only when it's not null.

What I mean is there can be multiple null values, but when they're not null they must be different. How can I do this?

Comment: What DB engine do you use?

Answer (score 4):

In SQL Server 2008 and above you can specify a condtion on your index

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Filtered_Index_Name ON your_table (some_column)
WHERE some_column IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Actually it's 2014 version. My bad.

Comment: Put an Index Name between INDEX and ON. Something like: ...INDEX IX_SOMECOLUMN ON your_table....